# MySQL database design of an online video education website

Tags: mysql, database

I am planning on a website that offers users training videos on multiple subjects, users can view videos, check their view history, comment on videos, taking relative exams and gain badges/certificates if they succeed in the exam. Also they can submit live questions when they had a problem during the video. ALso there will be a forum where users can help each other out and add friends, send messages, etc. WIth this idea in mind, I am now designing the database, but I had no experience in database design before, so please review the following design and give me some suggestions on performance and best practices.  Thank you all in advance.

There are

**USER PROFILE**

username    VARCHAR

id          INT

Type            ENUM

Email           VARCHAR

Date_created    TIMESTAMP

Date_modified   TIMESTAMP

Pass            VARBINARY

Name            VARCHAR

certificates    VARBINARY

Ranking_points  INT

Gender          ENUM

DOB         DATE

Avatar_url  VARCHAR

---

**VIDEOS**

Title           VARCHAR

id          INT

Category    ENUM

Description TINYTEXT

Date_created    TIMESTAMP

Tmp_name    CHAR

File_name   VARCHAR

Size            MEDIUMINT

Subtitle_url    VARCHAR

Liked_count INT

Shared_count    INT

Tags            ENUM

---

**CATEGORY**

Category    VARCHAR

id          INT

Description TINYTEXT

---

**RecentlyViewed**

User_id         INT

Video_id    INT

Viewed_date TIMESTAMP

---

**FRIEND_LIST**

User_id         INT

Friend_id   INT

---

**USER_QUESTIONS**

User_id       INT

Question_id   INT

Question_title    VARCHAR

Question_content  LONGTEXT

Date_asked    TIMESTAMP

---

**VIDEO_COMMENTS**
Title             VARCHAR

Video_id      INT

Comment_content   LONGTEXT

User_id       TINYTEXT

Date_created      TIMESTAMP

---

**USER_MESSAGES**

User_id         INT

Message_id  INT

Message_content LONGTEXT

Sender_id   INT

Date_created    TIMESTAMP

---

**ONLINE EXAMS/ASSESSMENTS**

id          VARCHAR

type            ENUM

exam_url    VARCHAR

description TINYTEXT

Date_created    TIMESTAMP

---

**EXAMS_TAKEN_BY_USER**

exam_id         INT

User_id         INT

Exam_result SMALLINT

Date_taken  TIMESTAMP

I have two more quesions:
1. I would like to allow comments on user comments, how would I design the database structure?
2. One video can belong to multiple categories, is it necessary to create a new table for video categories or just put a series of categories in the category field in the VIDEO table?

Answer (score 0):

you can use self-linked table for user comments. The table would look like this

```
Id ---- comments ---- parent_comment_Id
1    root comments         null
2    child comments         1
3    grandchild comments    2
```

About video category, it would be nice to have a separate table particularly for video category. And then you can scale category information such as category name, description and etc, in future. Considering user experience, it is quite common case that users want to check the category list first and then click through to get all the related videos.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I have done a further search and find the following which use the same method you give.   [link]http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5320605/advice-on-structuring-a-comment-system

Answer (score 0):

The overall structure seems to be okay, at least that looks pretty much like something I would do.

1.- **About comments on comments**:

I guess that the simplest design would be to add a **parent_comment_id** column to it. But that's a tricky one, because there would be a lot of NULL values either on **parent_comment_id** or **video_id**. So, another way around this would be to allow NULL values for **video_id** on **VIDEO_COMMENT**. In this scenario when a NULL in this column is found, you would know you're in presence of a reply to a user comment. Then, you'll have to found the parent comment on a second table:

```
USER_COMMENT
user_comment_id (primary key)
video_comment_id (foreign key to VIDEO_COMMENT)
comment (text)
created_date (date)
```

This is definitely not the cutest solution, but if you're troubled by performance issues, it could be worthy of a shot. You still have the same VIDEO_COMMENTS table (clean as before, no modifications to its structure). User comments on previous comment might not be that frequent, so you have them in a second structure, and not all over the same VIDEO_COMMENTS table.

2.- **About Video Categories**

Here I would create 2 additional tables: one for video categories (or tags) and a second for linking each video to its categories.

```
VIDEOS

Here I would drop the CATEGORY column


CATEGORIES

category_id (primary key)
title

VIDEO_CATEGORIES

video_category_id
category_id
video_id
```

In this case you can have a list of categories already stored, and the user would only have to select the ones he/she thinks right to his/her video.

I not recommend you to put multiple values on a same column since it's really a bad design issue. You couldn't provide the user with a list of categories (like the one I mentioned before). You would have, also, many duplicated values, typos, etc. Also, having several values stored in the same column makes editing unnecessary difficult: think how would you implement a user request to delete a category tag and add another. Of course, it isn't that hard, but it could be a lot simpler if you only had to delete individual references.

Comment: The comment solution you give has a very clear structure but I am just wondering whether allowing null values for video_id can cause some trouble. I will first go for the self-linked table solution. Using a separate VIdeo_categories table as you suggested sounds perfect for me. Thanks for pointing out the drawbacks of putting multiple values on a same column.

Comment: Generally NULL values wouldn't cause any trouble. The self linked table alternative is easier and should work fine.